# Linux Unity: Recognize dependent dll files

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, mono, dllimport

I have been trying to use `DllImport ("filename.dll")` in C# Unity Linux and found below things

Unity/C# is able to recognize independent .dll files ie
If dll A is not dependent on any other dlls it is recognized

Unity/C# is not able to recognize dependent .dll files ie
If dll A is dependent on dll B,dll C,dll D etc then dll A is not recognized, although all the 4 dlls( A,B,C,D dlls ) are in same location

.................................................................................................... .....

I have used dependency Walker for UnityInterface2.dll and found out that it depends on OpenNI2.dll, NiTE2.dll, msvcp90d.dll and kernel32.dll. I have placed all of these in project folder of Unity and also in 4.5 folder of mono , but the issue still persists.

Can I know how do I make C# code recognize a dll (UnityInterface2.dll) which depends on other dlls
(OpenNI2.dll, NiTE2.dll, msvcp90d.dll and kernel32.dll) in Linux ? Please help